# Facebook API - Get Life Events (graph-api or FQL)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

After reading extensively FB's documentation for graph-api and FQL I still can't find a way of obtaining my friends' life events (e.g. graduation date, anniversary, new home, etc).

The only event explicitly available in their documentation are birthdays (which is quite obvious).

I'm almost certain that it is possible to do the above because the IPhone App "Karma" (http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/karma/id457143798?mt=8) provides automatically that information after logging with FB (rulling out options such as crawling my friends wall, which would also be very unlikely due to FB's permissions)

**Any ideas? Possible FQL selectors that are not being documented?**

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Note that Karma's Android app does not provide life events.

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered here: [Grabbing Facebook life events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400522/grabbing-facebook-life-events)

These posts have a 'type', with a `code`. For instance, Relationship status change would be `code 62`, location changes would be `code 282`.

Look at the link

Answer (score 0):

Most of the changes to a user’s personal info (education, work, hometown, relationship status) just generate a “normal” status update message – AFAIK there’s no distinction made between those and other manual status updates.

So I’d say an app wanting to display that kind of info would have to go through the user’s status messages and filter out the ones it thinks to be relevant itself by looking at the story text.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but life events are not recorded as status updates, and again, i´m pretty sure Karma does not crawl FB.

Comment: Any update? I'm trying to get life events using the iOS SDK rn

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, education_history, work_history, relationship_status from user where uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

You can use this for education and work history or user, but for other your have to pass through their feed using

```
id/feed
```

and check story edge for filtration.