# How to Retrieve Facebook Life Events for a User

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to retrieve the Life Events of an authenticated Facebook User using the Graph API? It seems like this is simple to do for a [Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/milestones), but I can't seem to find a way to retrieve a list of Life Events/Milestones for a User. [This page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/life-event) appears to show how to display the details of a *specific* Life Event/Milestone (and since it references the `Born` Life Event and the `user_birthday` permission I'm assuming that it can be called for a User), but I can't seem to find a way to pull a list of all of a User's Life Events. Is there a way to do this via the Graph API (or some other method)?

Additionally, I've uncovered these StackOverflow posts on the matter of trying to read this info, but the info is pretty outdated (e.g. using FQL, which has been deprecated.)

- [Grabbing Facebook life events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400522/grabbing-facebook-life-events)
- [Facebook API - Get Life Events (graph-api or FQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857944/facebook-api-get-life-events-graph-api-or-fql)

Comment: So looks like the actual situation is that the `born` life-event is a special case since the `user_birthday` parameter existed before "life events" existed on Facebook. I do not see a way to query life-events at all though the API. It seems that a life-event post is considered a normal object and has no specific user based endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this for users. Only for pages: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/milestones

Comment: Is it available now?